# Can I do traditional web dev with SharePoint Online?

Tags: development, javascript, css, html

In other words, can I use a typical IDE like WebStorm, create some HTML, Javascript and CSS, then stick it on my Sharepoint site and will it work?

Here is a sample of what I'm trying:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test Sharepoint App</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
        (function() {
            Alert("Javascript works!");
        })();
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="Alert('Testing Javascript')">
    This is a test3 application with JS.
</body>
</html>
```

Neither of the alerts fire.

Comment: I never touch Visual studio, mainly use WebStorm, note the deployment of your files you have to take care of yourself. For CSR development check [iCSR](http://icsr.github.io) ans especially the [Cisar Chrome Extension](https://365csi.nl/cisar) Be sure to watch the [may 4th webinar on SharePoints future](https://resources.office.com/en-us-landing-the-future-of-sharepoint.html?wt.mc_id=usdx_evan_property_technet)

Comment: Is CSR the reason my javascript isn't working?

Comment: Just a note that due to licensing, you can't use SPO for public-facing internet sites. Also, while it might be *possible* to make a plain old html site within SPO, it definitely isn't the best tool for the job - better off just using a normal web hosting service, unless for whatever reason you have no other choice than to use SPO.

Comment: It's for our internal company which uses SPO for document storage.  We rely 100% on spreadsheets and such.  I want to replace one of the more complex sheets with a web app but I'm only versed in HTML/JS/CSS and don't want to learn more SP than I have to.  It would be nice to leverage lists and other integrated features eventually, but for now I'm just aiming for an HTML/JS/CSS proof of concept.

Comment: CSR is an additional technique to overwrite how SharePoint displays content. If you do not apply CSR it can not break anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to create custom HTML, Javascript and CSS in your SharePoint site.

A tool called `SharePoint Designer` is also available that shall help you to perform this. It is suggested that rather than this IDE it would better if you would use SharePoint Designer as it is designed for SharePoint specifically.

You would be able to download this [here](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjDz5uN7q7MAhVLOxQKHdQkBbkQFggbMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.microsoft.com%2Fen-in%2Fdownload%2Fdetails.aspx%3Fid%3D35491&usg=AFQjCNFvksrIw5QryRmRD1E_MkMoBpkVTg&sig2=KGCLFYSuaZ75RgesMlvsNg&bvm=bv.120551593,d.d24).

Also, please keep in mind that you do not mess up with the existing structure of SharePoint while doing this custom changes.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I've used Sharepoint designer and it "compiles" to an aspx file, right?  I do lots of custom web dev so I'd like to stick to my IDE and platforms of choice, that's kind of the whole point.  Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it does. You could very well stick to your IDE and perform these html, css and javascript changes.

Comment: Be sure to rename all your HTML pages to .ASPX when you want to use them. Otherwise SP will try to download them.

Comment: Got the HTML working after renaming to aspx, thanks.  Still can't get JS to work.